# によって and passive question

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, によって-passives

> 実力差は明確だった。
>   ライダーの速度は攻めれば攻めるほど減速していく。
>   目にも止まらぬ高速移動と連続攻撃。
>   **セイバーによって傷つけられた体を癒す自然治癒。**
>   後の事など考えない。
>   全ての燃料を燃やして畳み掛けなければセイバーを抑えきれない。

The fantranslation says:

> Natural healing that regenerates the wounds Saber sustains.

But isn't Saber the one who hurts Rider and Rider the one whose body is being regenerated?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fan translation is not correct and your intuition is.  The passive indicates the "agent" of the action by ～に（よって） (whether よって is added or not is a different topic).  So what it should really be is

> Natural healing that heals (Rider's) body who was injured **by** Saber.

So the lesson is don't always trust fan translations.

Comment: Thank you.  
I usually have been always wrong when it came to confronting me or the fan traslation, so I lost confidence there.  Anyway, what is the nuance よって conveys?

Comment: When the subject of the action is an inanimate object (i.e., it would ある instead of いる), then you add よって.  This puts to focus on the agent of the action.  Textbook example:  「モナ・リザ」はダビンチ**によって**描かれた。→　The Mona Lisa was painted **by** DaVinci.